# Cadwork how to solder separate parts in 3D

Tags: cad

I don't know if this is appropriate Stack Exchange site, but since it is for engineering I assume it is. In Cadwork v18 you could solder two **separate** parts (with shortcut `d`) so that it comes out as single part in production list. The image with parts highlighted that should be soldered, link provided below:

https://ibb.co/3Mm1whk

The problem is that version 18 is ancient and is not working properly with recent versions of Windows. Currently I'm using version 24, but now this seems to be not possible. Maybe someone knows any workarounds?

Comment: solder is used for connecting wires ... glue, screws or nails are used for connecting wood

Comment: have you asked Cadwork?

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, but that's how it's actually written in program mentioned. No I didn't asked yet.